# Iterate Global Variables With Imported Function?

Tags: python, import, global-variables

What I'm trying to do:

I have a function that I want to iterate values a, b, c, d, and z for.

```
def func1(x, y):
    if x > z:
        return 0
    if (x + y) > 0:
        return func2(x, y, a, c)
    return func2(x, y, b, d)
```

However, to find which values would produce the best `pass_rate`, I need to call a function -- let's call it `func3` -- in another .py which takes in `func1` and gives me a `pass_rate` for that specific instance of `func1`. Right now I'm trying to use global variables to be able to iterate a, b, c, d, and z; call `func3` which depends on `func1`; and compare `pass_rate` with previous `past_rate`.

Is there a better way to do this?

My current attempt was to have:

```
from another import pass_rate()
def find_rate():
    best_rate, best_a, best_b, best_c, best_d, best_z = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    global a, b, c, d, z
    while a < 100:
        ...
           if pass_rate() > best_rate:
               best_rate = pass_rate()
```

---

In the past, I kept changing the values for a, b, c, d, and z; saved the file; and in my terminal, opened another .py and ran func3 to see the pass_rate. But I   have a 1200000 possibilities to compare.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the function pass_rate()?  Also, what does func2 do?

Comment: @Al Avery the function for pass_rate() seems scrambled (?) -- in that it calls a function with a name 'nq82js' and does a whole bunch of other stuff I don't know how to interpret. Only thing certain is that it calls the (main py).func1 and returns a pass_rate. Func2 just returns an integer, depending on values of x and y.

Comment: Oh, I see - I didn't realize pass_rate() wasn't something you wrote.  Honestly I'm still kinda confused about what you're trying to do.  My understanding right now is that func3 takes as its parameter a single integer and makes a call to pass_rate() based on the value of that integer?

Comment: Basically this is a dice game, and the integer outputted by func1 is the num of dice to roll. func 2 is a strategy, and func3 calls on func1 for an entire game and calculates its pass_rate against another strategy. I want to cycle through a, b, c, d, and z and find out which values for those give me the best pass_rate for func1.